# Run Time Error 2147467259(80004005) while uploading excel data into access table

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ado

I am using Office 2016 and trying to upload data from excel to an Access Database. I am attaching the code below. However while running the code, getting the error message @ Newconn.open line.

I am using windows 10 64 bit system and have activated Access 16.0 object library and ActiveX  data object 2.5 library as well.

following code for your reference:

```
Sub test()


Dim Newconn As ADODB.Connection
Set Newconn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim RecordSet As ADODB.RecordSet
Set RecordSet = New ADODB.RecordSet
Dim Wb As Workbook, Ws As Worksheet

Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
Set Ws = Wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Newconn.Open "Microsoft.ace.oledb.16.0;File Source:=C:\Users\Shazra\Desktop\Test\test.accdb"
RecordSet.Open "Table1", Newconn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
RecordSet.Fields(0).Value = Ws.Range("A2").Value
RecordSet.Fields(1).Value = Ws.Range("B2").Value
RecordSet.Fields(2).Value = Ws.Range("C2").Value
RecordSet.Fields(3).Value = Ws.Range("D2").Value
RecordSet.Update
RecordSet.Close
Newconn.Close


End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Your [connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/) has incorrect keywords. Try `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Shazra\Desktop\Test\test.accdb;`

Comment: Thank you so much Parfait. I was putting these extra ":" in my code that was messing up with my code.